# How to send those Logstash events which has only "multiline,_xmlparsefailure" in tags to Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, socrata

I am using below config file so that only those events which have "multiline,_xmlparsefailure" tags can be send to the Elastic search. But in my case all of the events irrespective of tags are sent to the ES. Can someone please suggest?

Config file

```
output {   
       if "multiline,_xmlparsefailure" in [tags] {    
                      elasticsearch {    
                          host => localhost 
                          protocol => "http"    
                     }    
                     stdout { 
                          codec => rubydebug 
                     }    
             }
        }
```

Log Data:    Log file contains java stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code none of the results should go to Elasticsearch.
In any way try this approach - 
You need to treat these variables as different ones -

```
output {   
       if "multiline" in [tags] or "_xmlparsefailure" in [tags] {    
                      elasticsearch {    
                          host => localhost 
                          protocol => "http"    
                     }    
                     stdout { 
                          codec => rubydebug 
                     }    
             }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Vineeth. I have raised another qs at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219324/xmlparsefailure-thrown-by-logstash. Please have a look.