# _xmlparsefailure thrown by Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash is throwing _xmlparsefailure error for the below script and log file. Due to this for 1 log statement unwanted multiple events are generated. How can we remove parsing error?

```
input {
  file {
        path => "/novus/users/arun/a*"
        start_position => "end"
        codec => multiline {
        pattern => "(^\t)|(</stacktrace>)"
        what => previous
        }
   }
}
filter {
        grep {
                match => { "message" => "Exception" }
        }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost protocol => "http"
  }
}
```

Log file:

```
<event><date>5444-01-28-01:40:49.940</date><key>Exception</key><machine>ns9066</machine><timestamp>1422430849940</timestamp>><thread>UniqueIdRunnable_Runnable0</thread><product></product><novusid>ns9066.novusqc.1</novusid><application>NORM</application><environment>qc</environment><eventId>#23 Return relationships when MaxRelationships is equals to 10</eventId><requestId>0acd447514b2f7c4b8a3a497f1c</requestId><userid></userid><engineName>ns9066.novusqc.1</engineName><Class>RelationshipResolver.java</Class><Method>RelationshipResolver.getRelationshipGroups() </Method><eventlevel>warning</eventlevel><text>RelationshipGroup. normscalingloadRelationshipGroup. normscalingload</text>?><stacktrace>com.westgroup.novus.cci.CciRecordNotFoundException: RelationshipGroup. normscalingload
        at 2019com.westgroup.novus.norm.NormCciAccess_Cached1.retrieveRelationshipGroup(No>rmCciAccess_Cached1.java:68)
        at 2019com.westgroup.novus.norm.RelationshipResolver.getRelationshipGroups(Relatio>nshipResolver.java:3012)
        at 2019com.westgroup.novus.norm.splitmerge.GetUniqueIdRunnable.performTasks(GetUniqueIdRunnable.java:190)
        at 2019com.westgroup.novus.services.splitmerge.BaseRunnable.run(BaseRunnable.java:>107)
        at 2019com.westgroup.novus.commonutils.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:128)
</stacktrace><eventguid>2019</eventguid></event>
```

Comment: Only the xml filter adds the _xmlparsefailure tag, yet the configuration you claim to be using doesn't have such a filter.

Comment: Magnus - I was not aware of it that this error is coming because of XML filter. Actually it is in my config file after grep filter as given below:                                                                                                         xml {
            source => "message"
            xpath => [
                       "/event/date/text()", "date"
            ]
        }

    date {
        match => [ "date", "YYYY-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss.SSSS", "UNIX"]
    }

Comment: Just obesrved that _xmlparsefailure is still coming after disabling the XML filter.

Comment: In that case you probably didn't disable the filter properly. To further debug this, disable the elasticsearch output and use a regular stdout output to better see what the messages look like.

Comment: New event is getting generated after "...normscalingload" as shown in logs. Few words are also missing followed by "normscalingload".  Issue seems to be in pattern (input filter) in the config file.

Comment: Is Logstash 1.4.2 a stable version? If not, than which one? To me some basic functionality is not working like drop of an event, comparison operators etc in logstash 1.4.2.

Comment: Logstash 1.4.2 is currently the latest version and I would regard it as stable. It's likely that your problems are _not_ caused by bugs and I suggest you open separate questions for them.